# How can I specify a range in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know that a formula can be applied on a range of cells by utilizing an intermediate column, but can I directly specify a range in a formula somehow?

E.g., is it possible to do something like this, to get the sum of the results of dividing each cell in E12-E26 by each cell in C12-C26:

```
=SUM(E12/C12:E26/C26)
```

An answer, either positive or negative, would be accepted.

Comment: What you are doing is not very pretty: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209796/how-can-i-specify-a-range-in-a-formula

Comment: Excel usage is Data Science now? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter it as `=SUM(E12:E26/C12:C26)` followed by Ctrl-Shift-Enter on Windows or Command-Enter on Mac.It will then be treated as an array formula and the formula bar will show it as `{=SUM(E12:E26/C12:C26)}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sumproduct to avoid having to array-enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E12:E26/C12:C26))
```

Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.